# Variables unavailable when running a TAG build

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CI pipeline in Gitlab (relevant part only):

```
default:
    image: docker:latest

variables:
    DOCKER_APP_TAG: ${REGISTRY_URL}/${APP_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}

stages:
    - build

.config:
    only:
        - branches
        - merge_requests
        - tags
    except:
        - triggers
    tags:
        - prod

build-app:
    extends: .config
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build --target production -t ${DOCKER_APP_TAG} -f ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/etc/node/Dockerfile .
```

When I build from a branch (i.e. push to `main` branch) everything works well. The `docker build` command is ran with the proper value available in `S{DOCKER_APP_TAG}`.
However after I create a TAG in GitLab (and a release), the build on this GitLab TAG fails at the `docker build ...` line complaining that the docker tag is not valid:

```
invalid argument "/:e5dc27fd" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

The variables `${REGISTRY_URL}` and `${APP_NAME}` are not expanded. I have checked GitLab docs and the only limitations I see is if I was running in a service. But it is not the case.
What am I missing to expand properly the variables even with tag builds?